# Split float from beginning of string in C

Tags: c, string, tokenize

I'm currently writing a program in C, that can tokenize an arithmetic expression, but I've only provided a minimum, reproducible example here.

The following code successfully splits `-5.2foo` into `-5.2` and `foo`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "-5.2foo";
    float f;
    sscanf(str, "%f%s", &f, str);
    printf("%f | %s\n", f, str);
    return 0;
}
```

But if the string only contains a floating point number (e.g. `-5.2`), the program will print `-5.2 | -5.2`, so the string doesn't seem to be empty. Is there a way to split a float from a string in C and then store the remaining string?

Comment: You need to check the return value of `sscanf` before using any of the resulting variables. In the latter case you will find probably find it returns `1` which means it matched only the float.

Comment: Even moderately sophisticated tokenizers will not use `sscanf`. A [DFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) would suit you much better. Look up flex and bison.

Comment: @JeffHolt I have already looked into flex/bison and I'll probably use it in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`strtof()` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof), which has an argument to (optionally) return a pointer to the 'rest' of the input string (after the `float` has been extracted):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "-5.2foo";
    char* rest;
    float f;
    f = strtof(str, &rest);
    printf("%f | %s\n", f, rest);
    // And, if there's nothing left, then nothing will be printed ...
    char str2[] = "-5.2";
    f = strtof(str2, &rest);
    printf("%f | %s\n", f, rest);
    return 0;
}
```

From the cppreference page linked above (`str_end` is the second argument):

> The functions sets the pointer pointed to by str_end to point to the
> character past the last character interpreted. If str_end is a null
> pointer, it is ignored.

If there is nothing 'left' in the input string, then the returned value will point to that string's terminating `nul` character.

Comment: Is there something wrong with `float f = strtof(str, &str);`?

Comment: @Andy Using the *same* pointer for the first and second arguments is asking for trouble. What if you want to use `str` again, later. Also, in your case, you would be modifying something that shouldn't (can't) be changed - the address of the first element of an array.

Comment: In fact, for the code shown, using `f = strtof(str, &str);` will give this in clang-cl: `warning : incompatible pointer types passing 'char (*)[8]' to parameter of type 'char **' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]`

Comment: But that error wouldn't exist if I initialized the string as `char *str = "-5.32";`, right?

Comment: @Andy Sure - that would be valid code. But, as I said, just be careful when using such 'shortcuts'.

Comment: @AndySukowski-Bang the second argument of `strto` functions is marked as `restrict`, in theory you can not reuse it.